# jQuery getScript() function does not work in rails production mode deployed by Passenger along with Apache

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, apache, passenger

So I am trying to do a little bit polling for my rails app using jQuery's getScript() function. Here are my codes:

**script file**

```
function updatePredictionResults() {
    $.getScript("/predictions/pollAllResults.js?task_id=" + task_id + "&omim_id=" + omim_id);
}
```

This script, should call an action (**pollAllResults**) in the **prediction controller**, then render and execute the codes in **pollAllResults.js.erb** file. It works perfectly in development mode when testing using ***rails server***.

However, when I deployed my app using Phusion Passenger along with Apache, getScript() function seems not working -  neither the code in the controller or in the following javascript file is executed. There is also no error logs generated from the server. Anyone knows why? Many thanks!

**Update:**

Now I seem to know what the problem is - this is found in apache log:

```
 "GET /predictions/pollAllResults.js?task_id=1363034126&omim_id=180860&_=1363034264908 HTTP/1.1" 404 227
```

I don't know why this is happening... Strangely, even when I access this url directly, the javascript can be fetched and load..., but it keeps giving me 404...